# React-ReduxForm Password Confirmation not working?

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux-form

this is my validator function which I created using revalidat library. Where Password is my field.

```
const validatePass = matchesField('password')({
   message: 'Passwords do not match',
 });
```

I am applying this in Field level validate to my confirmPassword field. but It's not working perfectly it always show me 'Passwords do not match' . I don't Know what I am doing wrong.

```
<Field
                  name="confirmPassword" component={RenderTextField} type="password"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password" width="large" status="dafault" title="Confirm Password"
                  validate={[requireField,validatePass]}
                />
```

Anyone had used another Password Confirmation method. Suggest me

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```js
export const match = matchName => (value, allValues, props) =>
  value !== allValues[matchName]
    ? `This field must match with ${matchName} field`
    : undefined;
```

and then

```js
<Field
  type="password"
  name="password"
  label="Password"
  component={FormField}
  validate={[required, minLength(6)]}
/>
<Field
  type="password"
  name="confirmPassword"
  label="Confirm Password"
  component={FormField}
  validate={[required, match("password")]}
/>
```

Comment: This solution was buggy for me. I could not pinpoint why, but the `match` validation would not fail unless another validation in the form was also failing already.

Comment: For me, it works even if there are no other validation is failing. Maybe something else causes that bug?

Comment: I have to agree with @zigzag. It only fails if something else already fails beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Because Sinan's solution would not work for me, I'll post my less dynamic solution, field-specific matching solution

```js
export const matchPassword = (value, allValues) =>
  value !== allValues.password
    ? `This field must match with your password field`
    : undefined;


<Field
  type="password"
  name="password"
  label="Password"
  component={FormField}
  validate={[required, minLength(6)]}
/>
<Field
  type="password"
  name="confirmPassword"
  label="Confirm Password"
  component={FormField}
  validate={[required, matchPassword]}
/>
```